# Excel-Change Table Data to Normalize Data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create some web application using basic data from Excel
but the structur of data need to be adjust

Can anyone help me to change this table
**A B C D 

E F G H 

I J K L 

M N O P**

to

**A B

A C

A D

E F

E G

E H

I J

I K

I L

M N

M O

M P**

or something like that, 
I already try using this macro

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/05/07/vba-macro-normalize-data/

it works on hundreds data but when I try to using it on >12000 data it stop working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert matrix to 3-column table ('reverse pivot', 'unpivot', 'flatten', 'normalize')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the macro you pointed to is in lines

```
Rng.Offset(r, 0).Value
```

At least to me when I remove the reference to the range and replace it with reference to first cell for example like this

```
WS1.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value
```

it speeds up the macro tremendously = I ran it on 13000 lines and it was finished in 10 seconds using the macro from your link with only this adjustment.

Full macro with the change:

```
Sub NormalizeData()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a range to normalize data" _
, Title:="Select a range", Default:=ActiveCell.Address, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Rng Is Nothing Then
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set WS1 = ActiveSheet                       '<==== added this line
    Set WS = Sheets.Add
    i = 0
    For r = 0 To Rng.Rows.Count - 1             '<==== offset start changed to 0
        For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count - 1
            WS.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) = WS1.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value '<==== change
            WS.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1) = WS1.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value '<==== change
            i = i + 1
        Next c
        Application.StatusBar = r
    Next r
    WS.Range("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you give me an example for full macro change?
i try to edit this line 

WS.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1) = Rng.Offset(r, 0).Value

but its doesn't work

Comment: not "WS", because WS is your result sheet. You need to point it to your data sheet. I added the full macro into the answer. You can delete the lines "Application.StatusBar" - I only added them to see how fast the calculation is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'select a cell in your data before running
Sub DoIt()

    Dim data, n As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim result(), i As Long

    With Selection.CurrentRegion
        data = .Value
        n = .Cells.Count
    End With

    ReDim result(1 To n, 1 To 2)
    i = 0

    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        For c = 2 To UBound(data, 2)
            If Len(data(r, c)) > 0 Then
                i = i + 1
                result(i, 1) = data(r, 1)
                result(i, 2) = data(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    'adjust output location to suit
    ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Resize(i, 2) = result

End Sub
```

Input/output:

[image]